# Variable not updating in PHP

Tags: php, html

*[PHP newbie here, bear with me if this is a trivial question]*

I created an `HTML` form that, on submit, opens `submit_form.php`. Inside, I process the data entered into the form and send a confirmation email. I wrote a `function` for the mail-sending-process.
Inside the `.php` file, I have `PHP`, as well as `HTML` code. The important parts of the file look like this:

```
<?php
    $success = "undefined";

    /* ... */

    function send_mail($to, $from, $fromName, $subject, $message) {
        /* headers, etc. */
    
        if (mail($to, $subject, "", $header)) {
            $success = "true";
        } else {
            $success = "false";
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
        success? <?php echo $success; ?>
    </body
</html>
```

Now, when loading the `HTML` on the success site (`HTML` code below the `.php` script, in the same file), I put this code to verify whether the email was sent successfully:

```
success? <?php echo $success; ?>
```

...which presents the following output: `success? undefined`

#### Conclusion

That would lead me to the conclusion, the mail hasn't been sent *at all*, however, I do receive the email.
I'm guessing that the `HTML` code is being shown before the mail function is being executed.

#### Question

Is there any way to have the `HTML` execute *after* the mail function has finished?

#### Edit

Changed the title of the question from `Delay site change for php function completion` to `Variable not updating in PHP` since the (now fixed) issue was not the `HTML` executing before the `PHP`, but the variable not updating.
Thanks to @Adder for this!

Comment: Is the `mailto` in the same file as the `success? <?php echo $success; ?>`?

Comment: please share more code, as much as possible. might be a little bit trivial myself here, but  make sure the code you wrote is at the top of the page, before the html

Comment: Do you get into your send_mail function? try to var_dump something in there, and see if you even access the condition state

Comment: Well, since I receive the email, it probably executes the code, yes.

Comment: Does your function return success variable? afterall if it doesn't return anything it is pointless to have it there.

Comment: Yes, it says `false` on the `HTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `$success` variable is not in global scope. Use `global` to make it global.

```
function send_mail($to, $from, $fromName, $subject, $message) {
        global $success;

        /* headers, etc. */

        if (mail($to, $subject, "", $header)) {
            $success = "true";
        } else {
            $success = "false";
        }
    }
```

Variable scope means where the variable is visible. In php,variables local to a function don't live in the global scope by default.

Comment: Even though I created the variable **outside** the mail function? It's currently at the very top of the `PHP` part.

Comment: Yes there is two versions of $success, one in the outer global scope, and one in the functions scope. Thus you need global keyword.

Comment: Where do you call `send_mail` ? It needs to be executed before the `echo $success`

Comment: Woah! It actually works now. The `global` keyword was the key(-word, huehue)! Thanks!